# LLVM: Defining a new type via OCaml bindings

Tags: ocaml, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm using the LLVM OCaml bindings to build a compiler for an untyped language. Unfortunately, the only reference I have is `llvm.mli` from the source.

So, I tried declaring a `value_t` as follows:

```
let llar = [| i64_type;
              array_type i8_type 10;
              vector_type i64_type 10 |] in
let value_t = struct_type llar in
declare_global value_t "value_t" the_module
```

before I generate functions. What gets emitted is:

```
@value_t = external global { i64, [10 x i8], <10 x i64> }
```

To reference it later, I tried using `type_by_name`, but nothing matched; if I use `lookup_global`, I get a `llvalue` instead of an `lltype` (what do I do with it?). I guess what I really wanted is:

```
@value_t = type { i64, [10 x i8], <10 x i64> }
```

Hopefully, I'll be able to use `type_by_name` with this. Any hints on how to generate this?

Answer (score 0):

The functions you want are `named_struct_type` and `struct_set_body`:

```
let llvalue_t = named_struct_type context "value_t" in
struct_set_body llvalue_t llar false
```